# Confusing performance difference in innerHTML / textContent setters

Tags: html, css, performance, dom

This is a test comparing innerHTML/textContent performance, on existing as well as on newly created `style` elements: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-textcontent/3

The results imply:

- `innerHTML` and `textContent` perform exactly identical on newly created `style` nodes in every browser tested
- On existing `style` nodes, they perform exactly identical in Safari and Opera, but **`innerHTML` is faster in Firefox and Chrome**
- Replacing a `style` node with a newly created one is **faster than overwriting its `textContent` in Firefox and Chrome**, slower in Opera and no difference in Safari.

While it's not surprising that browsers differ in performance, I find the parts **in bold** rather surprising.

So, how could `innerHTML` be faster than `textContent`, and why would replacing some node be faster than replacing its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
[innerHTML, innerText, textContent, html() and text()?](http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/)

`InnerHTML` will return you all the content inside of the element, while `textContent` basically is trying to parse the content(get rid of the tags) when you access the element. What I guess the reason for the first point is, Google and Mozilla did some optimization to the `innerHTML`, using a pointer instead of heap obj as the reference, and that's why it is faster(pointer assignment vs obj manipulation). I assume FF/Chrome would have better performance than other browsers for `innerHTML` tag.

Seems the `textContent` trying to access its children nodes every time you access it.

for the second part, from the code you provided, js did the children nodes removal before calling `textContent`. As I said `textContent` is trying to access its children nodes and parse them while calling, it will be faster if it detects there's no child node appended.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say. I think you're talking about the getters here, not the setters